# how to detect routes component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have the following 2 routes in my app.module.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
      {path: 'property/:id', component: PropertyDetailComponent},
      {
        path: 'properties',
        component: ListingViewComponent,
        data: { title: 'Properties List' }
      },
      { path: '',
        redirectTo: '/properties',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ];
```

In my app.component.html I have the following component and outlet:

```
<side-nav></side-nav>

<contact-agent></contact-agent>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I want to show the side-nav for ListingView and contact-agent for PropertyDetail.

How can I conditionally show these?  Do I use the data/title property in routes?

Something like:

```
<div *ngIf="title === 'Properties List'">
<contact-agent></contact-agent>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider defining a secondary (also called auxiliary) route for the side-nav and contact-agent. Then you can route to the appropriate content in that secondary outlet.

You can find out more about secondary routes here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#secondary-routes

But basically, the html would look like this:

```
<router-outlet name=secondaryInfo></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Are you asking about the code to activate the routes? I have a code example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing  this.router.navigate([{outlets: { popup: ['messages']}}]); where popup is the name of the secondary outlet and messages is the route.